# Ping.SendAsyncCancel not working in Mono

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, ping

Trying to do a Ping.SendAsync with a timeout like 500 ms. The SendAsync timeout does not seem to be high precision so anything under 2000 ms is inconsistent.

I've attempted a workaround by sending a Ping.SendAsyncCancel after 500 ms WaitOne.

This code works perfectly on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2013 but on my Mac 10.11 with Xamarin 6.0.2 Mono 4.4.2 the SendAsyncCancel seems like its not setting the Cancel.

Here's my sample code, the WaitOne is set to 130 ms. The host is in Peru so it should go beyond the timeout if you're in the US.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            pingSendAsync();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static void pingSendAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***");
        string who = "div-core-rtr1.americatelnet.com.pe";
        AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);


        Ping pingSender = new Ping();

        pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int timeout = 12000;
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

        pingSender.SendAsync(who, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);

        if (waiter.WaitOne(130))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping Completion Signaled.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping Callback Wait Timed Out.");
            pingSender.SendAsyncCancel();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ping example completed.");
    }

    private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        PingReply reply = e.Reply;
        DisplayReply(reply);
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }

    public static void DisplayReply(PingReply reply)
    {
        if (reply == null)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine("ping status: {0}", reply.Status);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that if i run my test application as root on Mac i.e.(sudo mono pingtest.exe) the SendAsync timeout works with a low timeout.

Comment: I figured I would test that after looking at the source code for Ping.cs in the Mono project https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/7c4fb8caf0fb90251ec20cf135a3eba293090ee2/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/Ping.cs

There are 2 private methods SendPrivileged and SendUnprivileged.

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question!

Comment: Partly.
#1 SendAsyncCancel is still a no-op in Mono so I cant use that.
#2 I'm not sure how I would call Ping.SendAsync with elevated privilege in a Xamarin.mac Cocoa app.